Creating Mean Monthly Data
I have monthly data for each year spanning from 1950 to 2022, and each year contains 12 monthly timesteps.
How can I calculate and generate a single mean monthly data file that averages the values across these years by CDO? The desired output file should have 12 time steps, each representing the mean value for a particular month across the 73 years (1950-2022).
the cdo monmean in.nc out.nc
is not practical,because it take year mean.the output just has 1 timestep

First you need to merge the files
cdo mergetime year*.nc merged.nc

Then you can use ymonmean to calculate the seasonal cycle
cdo ymonmean merged.nc seasonal.nc

If you want further details on this functionality I made a short youtube video on this topic
